# Highlight substring in element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is the best way to highlight a specific substring in a div element in an event? 
By highlight, I mean apply some CSS style, like yellow background or something.

Basically I need a simple JS client side function of the form:

```
function (element, start, end) { 
  // element is the element to manipulate.  a div or span will do
  // start and end are the start and end positions within the text of that
  // element where highlighting should be.
  // do the stuff
}
```

Only one highlight will be active.

Comment: [What have you tried so far??](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I don't completely get what the function needs to be? Whats `start` and `end` for? And since you tagged _jquery_ , have you taken a look at any of the jquery [manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) functions like [.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will need to wrap the text that you want to in it's own `<span>` tag so you can give that text its own style.  Using your requested function definition, you could do it like this:

```
function (element, start, end) { 
    var str = element.innerHTML;
    str = str.substr(0, start) +
        '<span class="hilite">' + 
        str.substr(start, end - start + 1) +
        '</span>' +
        str.substr(end + 1);
    element.innerHTML = str;
}
```

You can then define CSS for the class hilite to control the style of that text.

```
.hilite {color: yellow;}
```

This assumes that start and end are indexes into the innerHTML of the first and last characters that you want highlighted.

If you want to be able to call it repeatedly on the same element (to move the higlight around), you could do it like this:

```
function (element, start, end) {
    var item = $(element);
    var str = item.data("origHTML");
    if (!str) {
        str = item.html();
        item.data("origHTML", str);
    }
    str = str.substr(0, start) +
        '<span class="hilite">' + 
        str.substr(start, end - start + 1) +
        '</span>' +
        str.substr(end + 1);
    item.html(str);
}
```

Comment: Gr8.  only thing is that this can only be done once.  another call and u will have two highlights.

Comment: @Ayman - If you want to replace the highlight, then just save the original unhighlighted innerHTML and operate on that rather than the current innerHTML.  You didn't make that a requirement in your question.

Comment: @Ayman - I added a version to my answer that you could call multiple times to move the highlight around.

Comment: your answer gave me the hint to solve my own problem. i"ll create an npm package for it.. (thumbsup)

Answer (score 4):

If you have no attached events or complicated HTML, you can just do search and replace on the HTML:

```
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/search/gi, function(match) {
    return '<span class="highlight">' + match + '</span>'
});
```

If you want something better, you can manipulate the DOM directly without using `innerHTML`, which will preserve events and work for more complicated HTML:

```
/*
 * Takes in an array of consecutive TextNodes and returns a document fragment with `word` highlighted
 */
function highlight_text_nodes($nodes, word) {
    if (!$nodes.length) {
        return;
    }

    var text = '';

    // Concatenate the consecutive nodes to get the actual text
    for (var i = 0; i < $nodes.length; i++) {
        text += $nodes[i].textContent;
    }

    var $fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    while (true) {
        // Tweak this if you want to change the highlighting behavior
        var index = text.toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase());

        if (index === -1) {
            break;
        }

        // Split the text into [before, match, after]
        var before = text.slice(0, index);
        var match = text.slice(index, index + word.length);
        text = text.slice(index + word.length);

        // Create the <mark>
        var $mark = document.createElement('mark');
        $mark.className = 'found';
        $mark.appendChild(document.createTextNode(match));

        // Append it to the fragment
        $fragment.appendChild(document.createTextNode(before));
        $fragment.appendChild($mark);
    }

    // If we have leftover text, just append it to the end
    if (text.length) {
        $fragment.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    }

    // Replace the nodes with the fragment
    $nodes[0].parentNode.insertBefore($fragment, $nodes[0]);

    for (var i = 0; i < $nodes.length; i++) {
        var $node = $nodes[$nodes.length - i - 1];
        $node.parentNode.removeChild($node);
    }
}


/*
 * Highlights all instances of `word` in `$node` and its children
 */
function highlight($node, word) {
    var $children = $node.childNodes;
    var $current_run = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < $children.length; i++) {
        var $child = $children[i];

        if ($child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            // Keep track of consecutive text nodes
            $current_run.push($child);
        } else {
            // If we hit a regular element, highlight what we have and start over
            highlight_text_nodes($current_run, word);
            $current_run = [];

            // Ignore text inside of our <mark>s
            if ($child.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && $child.className !== 'found') {
                highlight($child, word);
            }
        }
    }

    // Just in case we have only text nodes as children
    if ($current_run.length) {
        highlight_text_nodes($current_run, word);
    }
}

/*
 * Removes all highlighted <mark>s from the given node
 */
function unhighlight($node) {
    var $marks = [].slice.call($node.querySelectorAll('mark.found'));

    for (var i = 0; i < $marks.length; i++) {
        var $mark = $marks[i];

        // Replace each <mark> with just a text node of its contents
        $mark.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode($mark.childNodes[0].textContent), $mark);
    }
}
```

**Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wLkbbo5m/4/**

If you want even more features, just use a library (like [mark.js](https://markjs.io/)). There's no point in reinventing the *entire* wheel.

Comment: Except this is not the type of JS function that the question asked for.  And, you can't just assume that a replace operation will work.  For example, it won't work if there are multiple instances of the target string and the desired target is not the first one.

Comment: Using `innerHTML` is evil, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [mark.js](https://github.com/julmot/mark.js) which provides a simple and powerful [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) plugin :

```js
$('p').mark('sit');
```

```css
mark {
  background: orange;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mark.js@8.11.1/dist/jquery.mark.min.js"></script>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

#### In a React project

I was worried about how other libraries' DOM-manipulation would work in a React project, so I used [react-hightlight-words](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-highlight-words#usage) to solve this problem.

See [the table of props](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-highlight-words#props) for configuration.

Out of the box it takes search words instead of index ranges, but solves the same problem as in the question unless one is locked to indices. However, ***if*** that is the case, the `findChunks` property can be given a function to arbitrarily detect parts to hightlight. (See [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/highlight-words-core/blob/master/src/utils.js#L63) how the default `findChunks` is defined.)

Simple example from [the description on GitHub](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-highlight-words#usage).

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Highlighter from "react-highlight-words";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Highlighter
        highlightClassName="YourHighlightClass"
        searchWords={["and", "or", "the"]}
        autoEscape={true}
        textToHighlight="The dog is chasing the cat. Or perhaps they're just playing?"
    />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Install with `npm i --save react-highlight-words`

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="myElement">Hello everyone! guess Who</div>

<script>    
HTMLElement.prototype.mark=function(Str=null){var T=this;
    if(Str === null){ 
        if(T.oV){ T.innerHTML=T.oV }
        return T
    }
    var V = T.oV = T.oV || T.innerText, s = V.indexOf(Str), e = Str.length + s;
    if(s < 0){return;}//substring not found
    V = V.substr(0,s) + `<span style="background-color:lightblue">` + V.substr(s,e - s + 1) + `</span>` + V.substr(e+1);
    T.innerHTML=V;
    return T;
}

var E = document.getElementById("myElement");
  E.mark("Hello");//finds the string and highlight
  // E.mark();// revert to original text
</script>
```

working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/xwyqth6k/

Answer (score 0):

Try Highlighter.js library here:
https://gist.github.com/wliwanag/03d95916c7ba5d17e226

It supports:
   Highlighting of text in child elements.
   Use words in a text as search key (e.g. sample below will highlight "simply", "1500" etc..)

To use:

```
var searchInput = "simply 1500 bee y";
var textSource = $("#text-container").html();
var htmlSource = $("#html-container").html();

$("#text-result").html(highlightHtml(textSource, searchInput));
$("#html-result").html(highlightHtml(htmlSource, searchInput));
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wliwanag/dmohrq6m/)

Comment: This plugin uses `innerHTML`, which is evil, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Why using a selfmade highlighting function is a bad idea

The reason why it's probably a bad idea to start building your own highlighting function from scratch is because you will certainly run into issues that others have already solved. Challenges:

- You would need to remove text nodes with HTML elements to highlight your matches without destroying DOM events and triggering DOM regeneration over and over again (which would be the case with e.g. `innerHTML`)
- If you want to remove highlighted elements you would have to remove HTML elements with their content and also have to combine the splitted text-nodes for further searches. This is necessary because every highlighter plugin searches inside text nodes for matches and if your keywords will be splitted into several text nodes they will not being found.
- You would also need to build tests to make sure your plugin works in situations which you have not thought about. And I'm talking about cross-browser tests!

Sounds complicated? If you want some features like ignoring some elements from highlighting, diacritics mapping, synonyms mapping, search inside iframes, separated word search, etc. this becomes more and more complicated.

## Use an existing plugin

When using an existing, well implemented plugin, you don't have to worry about above named things. The article **[10 jQuery text highlighter plugins](https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-text-highlighter-plugins/)** on Sitepoint compares popular highlighter plugins.

## Have a look at [mark.js](https://markjs.io/)

[mark.js](https://markjs.io/) is such a plugin that is written in pure JavaScript, but is also available as jQuery plugin. It was developed to offer more opportunities than the other plugins with options to:

- search for keywords separately instead of the complete term
- map diacritics (For example if "justo" should also match "justò")
- ignore matches inside custom elements
- use custom highlighting element
- use custom highlighting class
- map custom synonyms
- search also inside iframes
- receive not found terms

**[DEMO](https://markjs.io/configurator.html)**

Alternatively you can see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/vpav6tL1/).

**Usage example**:

```
// Highlight "keyword" in the specified context
$(".context").mark("keyword");

// Highlight the custom regular expression in the specified context
$(".context").markRegExp(/Lorem/gmi);
```

It's free and developed open-source on GitHub ([project reference](https://github.com/julmot/mark.js)).

Comment: While this answer is relevant, I would put a disclaimer that this is your project. Also, I don't find the sentiment of your first paragraph very helpful. There are times when including other people's libraries is helpful, but saying that making a highlighting function is a "bad idea" is just wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately you have interpreted my answer wrong. What I wanted to say, is that if you develop your own highlighting function wou will _probably_ run into issues that others have already solved. I've seen hundreds of people answering with selfmade functions using a sinple RegExp replace with `innerHTML`, which is the wrong way if you want to avoid further issues (see my answer for the reasons). That said, I didn't wanted to say that experimenting is wrong. I wanted to say that it is safer to use an existing plugin, as it covers the necessary tests for you (not in worse plugins).

Comment: Also, there might be use cases where different highlighter plugins make sense (e.g. if you don't need to customize a plugin with options), which is the reason why I've referenced the Sitepoint article comparing the most popular ones. But I personally feel that mark.js is the plugin that is targeting all use cases, as it contains the things most plugins are missing: cross-browser unit tests (several dozens), written in the latest ECMAScript, hosted on GitHub with _enabled_ issues, available options to fit every requirement (diacritics, synonyms, iframes, separateWordSearch, ...) and maintained.

Answer (score 0):

This my decision react + bootstrap 5

```
  const highlightedLabel = (fullStr, highlightStr) => {
    const startIndex = fullStr.indexOf(highlightStr);
    const endIndex = startIndex + highlightStr.length;

    return (
      <span>
        <TableIcon size={16}/>
        <span className="text-dark ms-1">{fullStr.substr(0, startIndex)}</span>
        <span className="text-primary">{fullStr.substr(startIndex, highlightStr.length)}</span>
        <span className="text-dark">{fullStr.substr(endIndex, fullStr.length)}</span>
      </span>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

If you only want the specific text between start/end replaced (instead of every occurrence), it would look something like this:

```
function(element, start, end) {
    textToHilight = element.innerHTML.substr(start, end);
    element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.substring(0, start) + "<span class='hilight'>" + textToHilight + "</span>" + element.innerHTML.substring(end);
}
```